# Laravel Vue displaying from database table result using v-for directive not correctly

Tags: json, laravel, vue.js, controller, v-for

I have a problem with laravel and vue about displaying the result from database table find method. What I don't quite understand is why the v-for directive parsing the json result incorrectly.

Here is the Vue code :

```
<template>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Amount of Students</th>
            <th>Teacher</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr v-for="classroom in classrooms" :key="classroom.id">
            <td>{{ classroom.class_no }}&bull;{{ classroom.field }}&bull;{{ classroom.room_no }}</td>
            <td>{{ classroom.amount_students }}</td>
            <td>{{ classroom.teacher }}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit blue"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            classrooms : {
                "success": true,
                "data": { "id": 1, "class_no": 1, "field": "Architecture", "room_no": 4, "amount_students": 40, "teacher": "Bobby Fisher" },
                "message": "Find Classroom Detail"
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The json classrooms itself is actually the result from the controller :

```
    public function show($level)
    {
        $classrooms = ClassRoom::where('class_no', $level)->firstOrFail();

        return $this->sendResponse($classrooms , 'Find Classroom Detail');
    }
```

And here is screenshot of the wrong result :

[The result should be only a single row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vx69.png)

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO .. is this your full component code ?

Comment: no, but this code is just a piece of my full code. and this question is my 2nd after 4 years membership. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, as you are iterating over the classrooms which is an object having three keys, so the for loop is iterating over each key once.

If you only want to iterate over the `data` key then just return the data from the backend.

You can use a `v-if` condition to check whether the current key contains a class_no and if yes then display the row otherwise not.

```
<tr v-for="classroom in classrooms" :key="classroom.id" v-if="classroom.class_no">
    <td>{{ classroom.class_no }}&bull;{{ classroom.field }}&bull;{{ classroom.room_no }}</td>
    <td>{{ classroom.amount_students }}</td>
    <td>{{ classroom.teacher }}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-edit blue"></i>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working. But the v-if directive position is inside the <tr> element :

<tr v-for="classroom in classrooms" :key="classroom.id" v-if="classroom.class_no">

Comment: Hi, Good to know it worked, but it is not recommended to place the `v-if` and `v-for` on the same tag as per the Vue2 documentation[ https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-v-if ]

Comment: Thank you, I have read the documentation but in my case it is fits with documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your Vue data attribute, you want to use `v-for="classroom in classrooms.data"`.
And if you are getting the data from API then you don't want to assign the full response to your `classroom` data attribute but assign `response.data` to `classroom`, so you can do

`v-for="classroom in classrooms"`.

This will work unless your API returns data in a different format.

Comment: Yes, i am getting the result from API and I did change the classrooms variable and v-for statement into this :

<tr v-for="classroom in classrooms.data" :key="classroom.id">

and 

classrooms : {}

and the API function get data into this :

this.classrooms = response.data

the result is blank.

Comment: I don't have any problem with API result that have many rows, this problem happened with single row result and the format of json wich is different from the array json.

Answer (score 0):

you can check on JsFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/JManish/9qjvdy8n/2/

Make some changes in your classroom's data attribute.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th>Amount of Students</th>
        <th>Teacher</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(classroom, index) in classrooms.data" :key="index">
        <td>{{ classroom.class_no }}&bull;{{ classroom.field }}&bull;{{ classroom.room_no }}</td>
        <td>{{ classroom.amount_students }}</td>
        <td>{{ classroom.teacher }}</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-edit blue"></i>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
            classrooms: {
                "success": true,
                "data":[ 
                  { 
                    "id": 1, 
                    "class_no": 1, 
                    "field": "Architecture", 
                    "room_no": 4, 
                    "amount_students": 40, 
                    "teacher": "Bobby Fisher" 
                  }
                ],
                "message": "Find Classroom Detail"
            }
    }
  }
})
```

Hope this will resolve your parsing issue.

Comment: I can not altered the data clasrooms, since the data is a json resullt from controller. It is a json not an array of json. that's why i refer the controller too.

Comment: @Salamun-  make some changes in your  controller method instead of `firstOrFail()` use `get()` so you will get the list of classroms